# Why can't I serve my static files to Django?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate I have seen all of the other questions on similar topics and tried all of the solutions without effect.

My Django application is small and I am happy to serve the static files from the same server

In *settings.py* I have

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

I have uploaded my application to the server and run

```
python.manage.py collectstatic
```

All of my static files are in the appropriate directories under *staticfiles*

```
project-root
├── staticfiles
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── base.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── common.js
```

In my *html* I have

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

On loading the page I get the error

> Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I think this is because it cannot find the *css* file

Where am I going wrong? Do I need to provide any more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved by installing the [*whitenoise*](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) package. (I have not seen this recommended on the responses to similar questions around this problem)

```
pip install whitenoise
```

And add it to the middleware section of *settings.py*

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', 
    ...
]
```

All of my static files are now loaded and the site works perfectly with no further configuration

(I am assuming that the problem might have been caused by a quirk in the site's host's server settings.)

Answer (score 0):

> project_name - app_name - static - app_name - css/js file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app_name/style.css' %}">
```